# Assembly language programming problem in dos system initialization

Tags: assembly, dos, masm, x86-16

I have a little problem in understanding that why we are storing ES and AX values in STACK. This is mentioned in lines "line1" and "line2", respectively.

```
EXTERN RE_INIT:FAR

ASSUME ES:SYSINITSEG

PUSH ES
MOV AX, OFFSET SYSIN
PUSH AX

RE_INIT PROC FAR
RET
RE_INIT ENDP

;
;MOV THE DOS TO IT'S PROPER LOCATION
;

SYSIN:
.........code continues.........
```

Comment: Because the value of ES is not known until runtime.  One way around this is to push the segment you want to jump to, followed by the offset and then issuing a FAR RETURN. The effect is doing a runtime FAR JMP to SYSIN. It sets CS to what ES was and the IP (offset) of SYSIN. It is jumping to a piece of relocated code in a different segment but the same offset (SYSIN).

Comment: Thanks Michael, now I have understood the complete logic. Thank